# WebBrowser Problem if AllowsTransparency=True

Tags: c#

I'am using Smith Html Editor (https://github.com/adambarath/SmithHtmlEditor) in my program main window `AllowsTransparency=True` and web browser not showing, I can't do `AllowsTransparency=False` because I need this. I know this problem is related to win32. I searched the Internet and I can't find a solution. Is there any trick to fix this?

If I `AllowsTransparency=False` corners turn black.
[image]

Comment: Make sure that the control does not set transparency to 100% when AllowTransparency is set to true. Set Transparency = 0 or Opacity = 100 as the case may be.

Comment: @Shameel I tried but Web Browser does not have Transparency and Opacity properties. This problem is related to win32. Win32 Transparency is not supported I think.